# Wagtail – Add an author to blogpost model

Tags: django, wagtail

I am trying to add an author field to my blogpost model to be referenced later in my HTML:

```
author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.PROTECT, default=None)
```

But the first time I tried to migrate I got this error:

```
(1452, 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db`.`#sql-1_9a`, CONSTRAINT `blog_blogpage_author_id_8c179cec_fk_users_user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`author_id`) REFERENCES `users_user` (`id`))'
```

Which to me actually reads like what I want to archive, i.e. 'reference the user id'.
When I run `makemigrations` again, this error shows:

```
(1060, "Duplicate column name 'author_id'")
```

Am I so far  off here? How to add an author field in Wagtail?

Comment: set **`null=True`** in your field and do migration

Comment: Still the "duplicate column name" error.

Comment: Run `manage.py showmigrations`, check migrations contents, remove annecessary migration.

Comment: Seems like there is a reference to the User table already, try giving it a db table name and it will solve the issue